# Autogenerate UML diagram for my xcode project?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uml

I want to make a UML diagram for my xcode project automatically. Is there a tool out there that can do that for me? I've only found things like Omnigraffe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doxygen is able to generate *some* class diagrams using dot and graphviz. Here is a [sample project](https://github.com/hollance/SpeechBubbles) using it. But, to make it work you need MacPorts to `port install doxygen dot` and then edit the Doxygen text config file (included on that project) and set `HAVE_DOT = YES` and `UML_LOOK = YES`.

It's not complete and it's not much, but doxygen is the [lesser of two evils](http://developer.apple.com/opensource/tools/headerdoc.html). I wish someone knows a better option or a better tool appears.